# Query related to Manual Sharing and Sharing Button when OWD & Role Hierarchy is used

Tags: sharing, role-hierarchy, owd, sharing-button, manual-sharing

I just setup a new DEV ORG and setup below scenario for a testing

- The Accounts OWD is set as Private
- I have 3 users User_A (Admin Profile), User_B (Standard Platform) & User_C (Standard Platform)
- In Role Hierarchy User_A is in Top & User_B just below and last User C
  [image]

I can see Sharing Button on each Record level and looks all working perfect in normal scenario.

**I just tried to do below settings change and understand whats happening in background. I have manually shared an Account record from User A to User C as  `"Read Only"`. In which the record owner of this particular Account record is User_A. I have notice below behavior**

- User_C able to see the record as expected.

**My Queries are below**

1) When I checked via User_B he also able to see same record as of User_C. Is this because the reason that User_B is above role Hierarchy of User_C?

2) While login as User_B or User_C, the particular Shared Account record showing an Edit & Delete button. While clicking on it, its showing "Insufficient Privileges". Why Edit & Delete button is showing even though its shared as Read only? Is it a bug?

3) Why Sharing button is not showing up in User_C or User_B? I have changed the Sharing from User_A to `"Read/Write"` instead of `"Read Only"` still no Sharing Button is coming up for User_C or User_B? Is this because the reason that User_A is record Owner?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please find this useful link for more information. https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_bulk_sharing_understanding.htm

Please find comments to your queries below:

1) When I checked via User_B he also able to see same record as of User_C. Is this because the reason that User_B is above role Hierarchy of User_C?

**ANS: This is because "Grant Access Using Hierarchies" is always enabled for standard objects and cannot be disabled. If you go to Security-->Sharing Settings-->Account Sharing Settings, you can see the settings.**

2) While login as User_B or User_C, the particular Shared Account record showing an Edit & Delete button. While clicking on it, its showing "Insufficient Privileges". Why Edit & Delete button is showing even though its shared as Read only? Is it a bug?

**ANS: This is because the User B and User C don't have "Full Access(Read, write, delete, transfer)". You can only issue maximum "Read/Write" access through manual sharing. Full access can be granted using managed sharing i.e. sharing rules. The users above record owner's role hierarchy will automatically get full access. So this is as expected and not a bug.**

3) Why Sharing button is not showing up in User_C or User_B? I have changed the Sharing from User_A to "Read/Write" instead of "Read Only" still no Sharing Button is coming up for User_C or User_B? Is this because the reason that User_A is record Owner?

**ANS: Answer for this lies in answer#2. Only if you have full access, the sharing button(Transfer of the record) is visible or otherwise not.**

Hope this helps you.

Comment: Thnx for your reply and it helped a lot to understand. 
Are you able to clear my query on my second Question... 

Why the Edit/Delete button Appear in the Record details, even though User_A shared as Private? If its shared as Read/Write then the appearance of  Edit/Delete button make more sense. But why its displaying and showing error while clicking on it when shared in Private. 

Hope you got my query...

Comment: Hi Robert, displaying buttons on the page has nothing to do with the sharing settings you set. They will always appear weather you set the sharing settings as private or Read/Write. Ideally, the buttons should have been hidden.